# Java: Passing String variable in new File();

Tags: java, string, file, new-operator

I am developing an desktop application which reads specific XML Elements using XPath and displays them in text fields in a `JFrame`.

So far, the program ran smoothly until I decided to pass a `String` variable in the `File` class.

```
public void openNewFile(String filePath) {
    //file path C:\\Documents and Settings\\tanzim.hasan\\my documents\\xcbl.XML 
    //is passed as a string from another class.
    String aPath = filePath;

    //Path is printed on screen before entering the try & catch.
    System.out.println("File Path Before Try & Catch: "+filePath);

    try {
        //The following statement works if the file path is manually written. 
        // File xmlFile = new File ("C:\\Documents and Settings\\tanzim.hasan\\my documents\\xcbl.XML");

        //The following statement prints the actual path  
        File xmlFile = new File(aPath);
        System.out.println("file =" + xmlFile);

        //From here the document does not print the expected results. 
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        docFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);

        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        XPath srcPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        XPathShipToAddress shipToPath = new XPathShipToAddress(srcPath, doc);
        XPathBuyerPartyAddress buyerPartyPath = new XPathBuyerPartyAddress(srcPath, doc);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //
    }
}
```

If I define the `xmlFile` with a static path (i.e. manually write it) then the program works as expected. However, instead of writing a static path, if I pass the path as a string variable `aPath` it does not print the expected results.

I have done a bit of googling but failed to find anything concrete.

Comment: What's the value of the `aPath` variable? What do you expect it to print and what does it print instead. There are no static and dynamic strings. A string is a string. What's important is what characters the string contains.

Comment: @JBNizet value of aPath = **'C:\\Documents and Settings\\tanzim.hasan\\my documents\\xcbl.XML'**

It is captured in another class using file.getAbsolutePath(); and then using 'path.replaceAll()' the backslash escape characters are added.

I am expecting the **Document doc = docBuilder.parse(xmlFile);** to receive a valid file path so the file can parsed using the DocumentBuilderFactory. 

However it ONLY works if I manually type in the path - 

**File xmlFile = new File ("C:\\Documents and Settings\\tanzim.hasan\\my documents\\xcbl.XML");**

Comment: @All - I found one possible mistake, which again only works if i manually type in the file path. **Document doc = docBuilder.parse(xmlFile);** if **xmlFile** is replace with the actual file path it works. However when it is changed from **xmlFile** to **aPath** fails again. FYI, the failure does not shoot out any errors messages, it simply displays an empty screen where data is expected.

Comment: You shouldn't have double backslashes in your String. You only need them in a String **literal** because backslashes must be escaped, but the String itself should only contain single slashes.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the clarification and what you stated makes sense. However (sadly) it still didn't work. I remove the **path.replaceAll()** in the preceding class, so now instead of a String literal, the String contains the single slashed file path. Additionally, I modified the line at **Document doc = docBuilder.parse(xmlFile);** to include **System.out.println("@DOC "+doc);** the output is - **@DOC [#document: null]**. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the builtin object methods:

```
System.out.println("file = "+xmlFile.toString());
```

You could also use:

```
System.out.println("f = " + f.getAbsolutePath());
```

Also, if you're having issues wit hthe file not existing, check first then proceed:

```
File file = new File (aPath);
if(file.exists()) {
  //Do your work
}
```

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for the info. However, I only inserted the println statements to check the actual values received by the local variables. The main issue I am having is that **Document doc = docBuilder.parse(xmlFile);** is not receiving a valid file path to parse (or I assume so). Any thoughts?

Comment: Check to see if the path exist first. Adding example to answer. 1 sec.

Comment: Hi Jason, no luck unfortunately. Still the same issue as above. I know the file does exist in the file path, otherwise the catch statement shoot out an JOptionPane error message. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) like this `path.replaceAll("\\", "/")` to remove the backslashes, it will fail because the `replaceAll()` method expects a *regex* as the first parameter and a single backslash (coded as `"\\"`) is an **invalid** regex. To make it work using `replaceAll()`, you would need double-escape the backslash (once for the String, again for the regex) like this `path.replaceAll("\\\\", "/")`.

However, you don't need a regex! Instead, use the plain-text based [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) method like this:

```
path.replace("\\", "/")
```

Note that the names "replace" and "replaceAll" are misleading: "replace" still replaces *all* occurrences... the moron that decided on the name "replaceAll" should have chosen "replaceRegex" or something similar

#### Edit

Try:

```
path = path.replace("\\\\", "/");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I have changed from path.replaceAll() to path.replace("\\", "/"). The output when it reaches to **System.out.println("File Path Before Try & Catch: "+filePath);** is - **File Path Before Try & Catch: C:/Documents and Settings/tanzim.hasan/my documents/xcbl.XML**, which is perfect because thats where the file is.

Comment: However, the program failed to print  the results on the JFrame. I can't understand what is so different between writing **File xmlFile = new File ("C:\\Documents and Settings\\tanzim.hasan\\my documents\\xcbl.XML");** and writing **File xmlFile = new File(aPath);** Both contain a String which identifies a file called **xcbl.xml**. arrgghh!

Answer (score 0):

it is too late to answer this but...removing "" from my config file helped
I mean

```
    pathVariable=c:\\some\\path\\here
```

not this

```
    pathVariable="c:\\some\\path\\here"
```